# Getting duration of a particular frequency

Tags: c++, arduino, fft

I could use some help analyzing an audio input in arduino. This is my code (mostly from an existing example):

```
#include <arduinoFFT.h>
#include <PDM.h>
#include <Arduino_APDS9960.h>

#define SAMPLES 256 //Must be a power of 2
#define SAMPLING_FREQUENCY 16000 //On pin communication limit is 10k. Our microphone is on board

//Buffer for storing input values
short sampleBuffer[SAMPLES];
volatile int samplesRead;

//Timer variables
long t1=0;
long t2=-1;

//Fourier arrays
double vReal[SAMPLES];
double vImag[SAMPLES];

//Call back function
void onPDMdata(void);

//Led feedback
const int ledPin = 22; //red
const int ledPin2 = 23; //green
const int ledPin3 = 24; //blue

//Creating FFT obj
arduinoFFT FFT = arduinoFFT();

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) 
  {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. 
  }
  
  PDM.onReceive(onPDMdata);
  PDM.setBufferSize(SAMPLES);

  // PDM: single channel (mono) sampling at 16K
  if (!PDM.begin(1, SAMPLING_FREQUENCY)) 
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to start PDM!");
    while (1);
  }

   if (!APDS.begin()) 
   {
    Serial.println("Error initializing APDS9960 sensor!");
   }
  

  //Pin setup! 
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin2 , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin3, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);

  lightOne();
}

void loop() 
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  //Check if i'm close to something
  if (APDS.proximityAvailable()) 
  {
    // read the proximity
    // - 0   => close
    // - 255 => far
    // - -1  => error
    int proximity = APDS.readProximity();

    /*print value to the Serial Monitor
    Serial.print("Proximity ");
    Serial.print(proximity);
    Serial.print("\n");
    */
      //If something is really near i'll check for sound
      //Apparently can't see black
      if(proximity < 200)
      {
              lightThree();
              
             //If we have something to read
            if (samplesRead) 
            {
                    for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLES; i++)
                    {
                      vReal[i] = sampleBuffer[i];
                      vImag[i] = 0;
                    }
                        //Magic Fourier transformation! 
                        FFT.Windowing(vReal, SAMPLES, FFT_WIN_TYP_BLACKMAN_HARRIS, FFT_FORWARD); 
                        FFT.Compute(vReal, vImag, SAMPLES, FFT_FORWARD);
                        FFT.ComplexToMagnitude(vReal, vImag, SAMPLES);
                        
                        //Pick peak frequency
                        double peak = FFT.MajorPeak(vReal, SAMPLES, SAMPLING_FREQUENCY);
                      
                        if (peak >2500 && peak < 2800 && t1==0 )
                        {
                          Serial.println(peak);
                          t1=millis();
                          
                          //lightTwo();
                          //delay(250);
                          //lightOne();
                        }
                        if(peak < 2500 && t2<0 && t1>0)
                        {
                          t2=millis();
                          
                          Serial.print("TIME SPAN ");
                          //long n=t2-t1;
                          Serial.print(t2-t1);
                          Serial.print("\n");

                          t1=0;
                          t2=-1;
                        }
                       
                
                        //Reset sample counts.
                        samplesRead = 0;
            }
        
      }
      else
      {
        lightOne();  
      }
  }


 

}

//Call back function, invoked when data is available to be read.
void onPDMdata()
{
  int bytesAvailable = PDM.available();
  PDM.read(sampleBuffer, bytesAvailable);
  samplesRead = bytesAvailable / 2;
}

//Led functions to get feedback
void lightOne() 
{
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH);
}
void lightTwo() 
{
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH);
}

void lightThree()
{
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPin3, LOW);
}
```

So basically this little script uses arduino to capture and transforming audio checking if i can sense a particular frequency (2550-2800).
Frequency recognition is working fine, but i'd also like to know how long last in time such frequency peak.
Could some one address me to a solution? I've a very elementary knowledge of Fourier Transformation ( i know how and why we should use it), so even if you can't provide me a solution i'd be glad just to have some documentation that could help me to arrange a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Short Term Fourier Transform partially converts from the time domain to the frequency domain - your time resolution goes from 16000 down to 16000/256, but you still know which frames have a peak and which don't.

I'm not entirely certain about your `SAMPLES` and `samplesRead` - is it possible that your Arduino can have samplesRead>0 but <SAMPLES? If so, you might need some additional buffering yourself, but this isn't certain.

Otherwise, the timing is straightforward. You get 16 samples per millisecond, so each set of SAMPLES that you pass to the FFT represents SAMPLES/16 milliseconds. The FFT trades time resolution for frequency resolution, so you can only measure the peak length with this 16 millisecond granularity. And you do that by simply **counting** the number of FFT frames with a peak.

Additional helpful tip: You probably want to check if the major peak found is indeed much higher than the other values. 10 or 20% is just normal variation, you probably want a peak that's 10x average.